# find out un-authored css in a html page

Tags: css, debugging

For optimizing load time for a web page, a practicable way is to remove all the unused css. Unfortunately, in the reverse direction, is there an existing lib or tool for listing all the css selectors in html which have not been authored in css? Any kind of information or help is appreciated.
Thanks!~

Answer (score 0):

There is a firebug tool called [Css Usage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/) You can use to do just that.

Comment: that is really a good tool, but it seems it only list the unused style. I'd like to know which css classes available in html but not in the css file. thanks~!